# Error installing datastax cassandra 2.0

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra-2.0, datastax, opscenter

I am unable to install datastax cassandra 2.0 on Ubuntu. I can install 2.1 without any problem but I need to run 2.0.9. I am following these steps, is there any thing that I can do to install 2.0?

```
echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
curl -L http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install  dsc20
```

and the error is:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install  dsc20
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dsc20 : Depends: cassandra (= 2.0.10) but 2.1.0-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sudo apt-get install dsc20 cassandra=2.0.10 -V
```

Comment: This was still giving me the same problem.  Changing it to cassandra=2.0.* fixed it. As seen in https://git.openstack.org/cgit/stackforge/poppy/commit/docker/cassandra?id=686630e56ef5fdaf0aa0cf77c26fec2a45f8ddd7